# Caching something with RXJS until a certian condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to make an RXJS Observable which will essentially act like a cache. Usually I can just use `shareReplay` for this, however the data I am trying to cache is based on the user, so needs to reset.
The following does *almost* what I want:

```
const myObservable = userProfile.pipe(
  switchMap(profile => loadData(profile)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Now the data is loaded on the first subscription and it won't be loaded again until a new user profile comes along. However this does not quite work, because a subscriber that subscribes while the new data is being loaded still receives the old data which is cached. This causes the UI to display the old data from the previous user. To circumvent this I did the following:

```
const myObservable = userProfile.pipe(
  switchMap(profile => loadData(profile).pipe(startWith(null))),
  shareReplay(1),
  filter(v => v != null)
);
```

This now works great except for one thing: Once a new user logs in, the data is immediately loaded, *even though there are currently no subscribers* to `myObservable`. This happens, because `shareReplay` never unsubscribes from the source. You can make it do so by using `refCount: true` - but that will disable the caching behavior I want, because the replay buffer is cleared when there are no more subscribers.

I have no idea how to achieve this using RXJS operators or if I need to write a custom operator.

Comment: This is not clear "Once a new user logs in, the data is immediately loaded, even though there are currently no subscribers to myObservable". When a new user logs in the application reloads or?

Comment: Tracking with you until the last paragraph. Could you clarify the behavior you want there? Also I didn't think ```shareReplay``` "subscribes" to anything. If your ```loadData()``` function is getting run, there must be some active subscription somewhere... sure there's not an async pipe or anything still listening?

Comment: > When a new user logs in the application reloads or?


No, this is in a mobile app (Ionic), so no reloading happens upon logout.

Comment: @AdamDunkerley Yes there is a subscription, but eventually it unsubscribes. But shareReplay will keep the "inner subscription" alive, even after all "outer" subscriptions are unsubscribed already.